# Shimano Nexus 3 clicking free-wheel-mechanism-like noise

Tags: shimano, internally-geared-hub, noise, nexus

I have assembled a bike with new Shimano Nexus 3 (SG-3C41) internally geared hub. In the lowest gear the hub is silent. However in the middle and highest gear it makes a clicking noise similar to free-wheel mechanism while not pedaling. The clicking is faster in the highest gear at the same speed.

Have I made an error in assembly or is it normal for this model?

Can I somehow get rid of this clicking or at least make it quieter by greasing some parts?

Side note: I couldn't fit the original grips in my setup, so I have Sram 7.0 rear 8 gear grip shift controlling the hub. I tried setting the grip between the gears, so I'm almost certainly sure this isn't the cause of clicking, but just in case...

Comment: I remember that the old 3-speed hubs of my youth always clicked loudly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is normal - cogs of 1st gear turn slower than that from 2nd and 3rd gear, so are overrun and click into hub housing. You can "silent" it a bit by opening the hub and greasing hub housing, where the cogs work.

Answer (score 1):

I have a Sturmey Archer 3 speed hub and have similar ticking sounds.

I suspect it's the various parts of the [planetary gear](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Epicyclic_gearing#Compound_planetary_gears) meshing and rolling against each other. It's a pretty complex little mechanism.